# Regex for removing characters between brackets

Tags: regex

I am using the following regex to remove items in a sentence that falls within brackets

```
\(.*?\)


So in this sentence anything between (DFKJERLjDLJLF) gets removed.
```

But if there are more than one brackets in a sentence, I want to target only the last bracket. How do I change my regex?

```
So in this sentence (only) the last bracket and its contents (DFKJERLjDLJLF) gets removed.
```

Update: I tried using `\s\([^)]+\)$` in my regex tool but it is not matching

Comment: what language are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is the example](https://regex101.com/r/v3zuCP/1)

```
.*(\(.*?\))
```

.* matches every character and moves the position to the end, when it bounce back
and then `(\(.*?\))` find the first match in (), i.e. the last match from the start.

Answer (score 1):

A python solution to this is:

```
def remove_last_brackets(string):
    return re.sub(r'^(.*)\(.*?\)?([^()]*)$', lambda x: x.group(1) + x.group(2), string)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer without language context.

The global flag, supported on most regex systems, allows you to match all occurrences of a string directly.

Alternatively, you could store the first location of a match and then start future searches at that location, and repeat until there are no matches.

Comment: This should be a comment.